# How to get AMQP queues stats using any PHP lib?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I found answers how to get queue stats in Python, Java and JavaScript, but it's very strange that I can't find how to do it with PHP libs like [PECL AMQP](http://php.net/manual/pl/book.amqp.php) or with [php-amqp](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) lib.

Only one possible option I found was to send requests directly to rabbitMQ api http://server-name:15672/api/

Is there any other option with PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/alchemy-fr/RabbitMQ-Management-API-Client library to query RabbitMQ Management API.